# GMS for Android Wearable communication

Tags: android, bluetooth, wear-os, android-bluetooth

I am currently working on Android Wearable application development and I have couple of question regarding Android APIs for Wearables.

1) I am wondering why Android uses GMS (Wearable APIs which in turn use Bluetooth)  for communication between Wearable and Handheld device(smartphone)? And why Bluetooth APIs for Android are not being used for communication between these devices?

2) Why Wearable APIs are packed inside separate library "Google APIs for Android" and why are they not part of Android SDK or framework?

Thanks for in  advance!

Comment: Android Wear itself is not an open-source project. Google is under no obligation to reveal the protocol of what is a closed-source project which extends from the OS on the watch to the Wear App on the phone.

Comment: The Wear APIs use a variety of protocols: direct Bluetooth when it's available, but also WiFi and cellular data (via Google's servers) when the Bluetooth link isn't connected. In addition to the closed-source aspect that @Morrison Chang mentioned, this use of Google's servers is another reason that it's packaged in GMS.